# POP-UP UIView "IMDB App" style

Tags: ios, uiview, popup, window, uipopovercontroller

Is there an easy way to accomplish this kind of pop-up window (like there is with UIPopoverController) or should I build it from scratch?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1898217/la-foto.jpg

Answer (score 5):

You can make something like this from scratch pretty easily. The trick is to make your popover view controller have a full screen transparent layer

From your main view:

```
self.popoverController = [[PopoverController alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:@"PopoverViewController" bundle:nil];
self.popoverController.view.frame =
    CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:self.popoverController.view]; // view is the transparent background
[self.popoverController viewWillAppear:NO];
```

Now its just a matter of implementing viewWillAppear if you want transition effects:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.fadeView.alpha = 1.0f;
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    [self slideIn];
}

// Slide in with whatever effects you want your popup to use
- (void) slideIn {
    //set initial location at bottom of view (my popup slid in from the bottom)

    CGRect frame = self.configView.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    self.configView.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.configView];

    //animate to new location, determined by height of the view in the NIB
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"presentWithSuperview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    self.view.alpha = 1.0; // fade in background

    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height -self.configView.bounds.size.height);
    self.configView.frame = frame; // animate in popup

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) slideOut {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    // Set delegate and selector to remove from superview when animation completes
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    // Move this view to bottom of superview (my popup slides back to the bottom when finished)
    CGRect frame = self.configView.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    self.configView.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

// Finally remove the views when you're done animating out.
- (void) animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation"]) {
        [self.configView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

For bonus points you can make the transparent background a control and have it detect touches for when the popup should go away. I used interface builder to call an action which calls slideOut.

Comment: Nice one! Since we are building it from scratch, how difficult is to animate the view with that 3d flip that has the IMDB one? I've never done 3d animations, not know even where to start. Thanks Winder.

Comment: CATransform3DMakeRotation was the answer. :-)

Comment: Can anyone explain this code in a little detail please? Much obliged. thanks!

Comment: The first block of code would be in your existing application, triggered by something like a button press. It is simply loading a view controller from a NIB and displaying it. The second block of code is inside the view controller implementation, there are two tricks. First that you have two views, one of which is semi-transparent, the other is positioned offscreen. Now when viewWillAppear is automatically called it just has to animate the pop-up in. Finally when you're done with it, call the slideOut method to animate it out.