# How to tell when a subView is removed a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, subview

Basically i wanted to implement a popup UIView so i followed what was posted here
[POP-UP UIView "IMDB App" style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103917/pop-up-uiview-imdb-app-style)

This works very well. However i have one query. My main view is a tableView. so when a view is popped up i disable scrolling in the table. Now when the popup subView is removed, i need to re-enable scrolling. How do i achieve that? i can't use willRemoveFromSuperview because the popup view is loading a different NIB altogether.

Should i use Notifications?

hope i was clear with explaining the scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you re-enable scrolling the viewDidUnload method of the popup view? I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I've seen a lot of people close views out WITHIN the view - sure, you can do that, but then you get the "how do I know it was closed out?". What you do is follow Apple's suggestion and create a @protocol for your view class. So NOW when you create the popup you also register a delegate. When the popup is closed it calls the delegate and it is from THERE you close the popup and reenable scrolling.

Creating a protocol and a delegate for every subview is a bit of an annoyance, but it solves SO many problems.

Comment: This worked perfectly, @Feloneous Cat. Thanks! It's a very effective method too!

Comment: I have implemented protocols before but in this example I am not sure how to do it. Could you refer me to the place in Apples documentation where they recommend this or any where else that would help me understand how to implement a protocol for this? Thanks

Comment: i can explain how it works:

in your homeViewController you have a button, which upon clicking opens up a popup of popupViewController.
 
So you define a delegate method in popupVC and a protocol with a method - (void)scrollingChanged; in it.

Implement the popupDelegate in your homeVC and also the method scrollingChanged where you can make the necessary changes. Hope this made it clear. See Feloneous Cat's answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feloneous Cat has the correct answer. This is the perfect use a `@protocol` in your popup view along with a registered delegate. Something is triggering that popup view to close. Whatever that trigger is, call the protocol and the delegate can handle the situation as needed.

Furthermore, when protocols are used correctly, your code becomes very reusable within a project as well as in other projects.

Comment: Thanks @dredful. This worked perfectly and is a very effective method too!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is subclass `UIView` and override `removeFromSuperview` to send a notification.  I don't think there's ever a case where a view gets removed without using the `removeFromSuperview` method.